# Prevent Unity Editor Inspector Checkbox from having any action in-game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, checkbox

To sum this up the best I can:
I have some code that sets a boolean value to true. When this little checkbox is enabled, it works as intended, allowing the game to function normally.
[image: When set to true it does as expected]

However, later on the code at some point sets this boolean to false (remember, it is a **public** boolean). Unfortunately, when this checkbox enabled. The console reads "true, false, true, false" etc. which prevents the desired outcome.
[image: You can see that the output is true, false, true, false when the checkbox is enabled]

If I disable this checkbox, then the output reads "false, true, false, true" etc. which prevents anything from working.
[image: Nothing works!!!]

Is there a way of disabling this stupid checkbox from having any effect in the game? I have tried [system.nonserialized] to no effect.
At least, is there a way to disable and enable this checkbox in code?

As requested, here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class startAgain : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool start;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //start = true;
    }

    public void use ()
    {
        start = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        print(start);
    }

    public void rest()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Waittostart());
        Vector3 ball = GameObject.Find("Ball").transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        Transform lpadlx = GameObject.Find("Player Paddle").transform;
        Vector3 lpadpos = lpadlx.position;
        Vector3 leftpaddle = GameObject.Find("Player Paddle").transform.position = new Vector3(lpadpos.x, 0, 0);

        Transform rpadlx = GameObject.Find("AI Paddle").transform;
        Vector3 rpadpos = rpadlx.position;
        Vector3 rightpaddle = GameObject.Find("AI Paddle").transform.position = new Vector3(rpadpos.x, 0, 0);
    }

    IEnumerator Waittostart()
    {
        print("RUNNING!");
        start = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        start = true;
    }

}
```

(please note that some of this was used for debug, so some bits will be out of place just to test it!)

Thanks! I hope this was clear enough.

Comment: Where is the code for that class?

Comment: Please check the code which I have added to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I removed the script from the game object it was attached to, and then set the boolean as static, and referenced it from there.

Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I tested the supplied code, and it worked as I would expect--the checkbox in the UI stayed in sync with the state of the `bool` in the running code. The console logs also consistently showed the correct value.

I was able to replicate the behavior you described by adding a second instance of the script. Try changing your `print` call to `print($"{start} {GetHashCode()}");`. You should see only one value for `GetHashCode()` in the Console. If you see two values, you definitely have two instances of the script.

Comment: By the looks of things I only get 1 value for gethashcode, but it still alternates between false and true and in turn hash code "11434" and "11362". Also if I remove the script from the object I don't get the same alternating pattern however I do get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" due to me trying to access a script that is not connected to an object.

Comment: Alternating between hash codes, like you described, is what I meant when I said "two values." Your scene had two instances of your script. Each instance has a different hash code. One instance had `start = true`, and the other had `start = false`. Each instance writes its state to the console once per frame, which is why the value appears to alternate.

Comment: You should use `Debug.Log(start, this);` .. by providing the context you can click on a log entry in the console and it highlights the object where the message came from. In general: don't print out stuff every frame ;)